# Properly hide index.php and questionmark

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

With some tutorial i hide index.php in my URL thanks to htaccess.txt code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

But there is a small problem with questionmark in URL:
https://kamafin.cz/?kontakt

Code of my menu:

```
<ul>
...
<li><a href="index.php?kontakt">kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['kontakt'])){
include 'includes/kontakt.php';
...
}
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: _“But there is a small problem”_ - and that problem actually _is_ … what?

Comment: And what’s with `href="index.php?kontakt"`, I though the purpose of the whole exercise here was to get rid of `index.php`? So why is that still there then?

Comment: What you found there seems to be a rather weird thing to go about this in the first place, this is not how stuff like this is normally done.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking 'kontakt' parameter from GET so '?' separate URL and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule like this in you .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/kontakt$ /index.php?kontakt= [L]
```